# How do I download python Correctly

Tags: python

I've been trying to start a python program up, but apparently I do not have python.exe installed. I installed Python 3.6 but every time i check i do not have:

C:\Python36\python.exe

is there another way to download this? or get this?

Comment: after install python you should add to the PATH environment variable, the path of  the installed python.

Comment: i did add it to the Path of Environment Variables but it didn't work.

Comment: Python 3.6 default installation path isn't C:\Python36, did you choose that manually when you installed it?

Comment: i don't think so, ill reinstall it and do that